# Difference between v.assign(v + 1) and v = v + 1 in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, assign, arithmetic-expressions

The following Tensorflow code works fine and `v1` becomes [1., 1., 1.]

```
v1 = tf.get_variable('v1', shape=[3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
v1 = v1 + 1 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print (v1.eval())
```

The following code segment also gives us the exactly the same result as the above. `v1` becomes [1., 1., 1.] if we run `sess.run(inc_v1)`.

```
v1 = tf.get_variable('v1', shape=[3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1 + 1)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(inc_v1)
    print (v1.eval())
```

However, the following code causes an error.

```
v1 = tf.get_variable('v1', shape=[3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
v1 = v1 + 1 
inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1 + 1)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(inc_v1)
    print (v1.eval())
```

The error is as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

Could you please tell me why it causes an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensors and Variables are different objects in TensorFlow

```py
import tensorflow as tf


def inspect(t):
    print('\n %s\n-------' % t.name)
    print(type(t))
    print(t.op.outputs)
    print('has assign method' if 'assign' in dir(t) else 'has no assign method')


v1 = tf.get_variable('v1', shape=[3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
inspect(v1)
v2 = v1 + 1
inspect(v2)
```

gives

```
 v1:0
-------
<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable'>
[<tf.Tensor 'v1:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>]
has assign method

 add:0
-------
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
[<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32>]
has no assign method
```

Hence, `v1:0` is really the variable itself and `v1` has the method `assign`. This makes sense because it is just a reference to a float value.
On the other hand, `v2 = v1 + 1` results in the output of the `add` operation. So `v2` is not a variable anymore and you cannot assign a new value to `v2`. Which operand of `add` do you expect to be updated in this case?
Whenever you use `v1` think of the `read_value()` operation from `v1` being used:

```py
v1 = tf.get_variable('v1', shape=[3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
inspect(v1)
w = v1.read_value()
inspect(w)
v2 = v1.read_value() + 1
inspect(v2)
```

gives

```
 v1:0
-------
<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable'>
[<tf.Tensor 'v1:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>]
has assign method

 read:0
-------
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
[<tf.Tensor 'read:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32>]
has no assign method

 add:0
-------
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
[<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32>]
has no assign method
```