# tf.confusion_matrix with tf.assign_add

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use `tf.confusion_matrix` with `tf.assign_add` in order to update a confusion matrix every global step.

```
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.int16,shape=[None,])
y_pred = tf.placeholder(tf.int16,shape=[None,])
cm = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=y_true,predictions=y_pred)
cm_inc = tf.assign_add(cm, cm) #error

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 
    for i in range(5):
        feed_dict={y_true:[0,1,0,0],y_pred:[1,1,0,0]}
        print(sess.run(cm_inc,feed_dict=feed_dict))
```

However I get

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign_add'
```

Is there a way of accessing the actual matrix of the confusion matrix object i.e. `cm` to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

You get

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign_add'

because `assign_add` only makes sense for variables (see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167200/7443104))

As you know the number of classes you should create an empty variable (all entries zero) and `assign_add` the result to this variable like

```py
import tensorflow as tf

NUM_CLASSES = 4

y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.int16, shape=[None, ])
y_pred = tf.placeholder(tf.int16, shape=[None, ])
cm_diff = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=y_true, predictions=y_pred, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)

cm = tf.get_variable('confusion_matrix', [NUM_CLASSES, NUM_CLASSES], dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
cm_inc = tf.assign_add(cm, cm_diff)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(5):
        feed_dict = {y_true: [0, 1, 0, 0], y_pred: [1, 1, 0, 0]}
        print(sess.run(cm_inc, feed_dict=feed_dict))
```